# How do I move my mouse on my tablet without clicking instead of just having it teleport?

Tags: tablet, wacom

I am using a Huion H420 and Ubuntu 22.04.

All I read online was to go to settings and change it there, but when I go to settings and click on Wacom Tablet, it does not detect the tablet at all. How do I fix this?